# Obtener valor Drop Down List Cuando carga mi pagina

Tags: visual-studio, asp, listview

Estoy trabajando con un `listview`, el cual completo los datos desde `SQL`, en la misma utilizo 2 filtros, que el `'radio button group'` y el valor seleccionado desde el `'drop down list'`.

Si bien la consulta funciona y me presenta los datos, al abrir la pagina por primera vez, me lo presenta de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando los datos que posee dicha consulta son estos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quise obtener y capturar el valor seleccionado en el `Page_load` y haciendo un `databind()` del `ListView`, pero se me presenta la misma situación.
¿Me pueden dar alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Saludos!

```
    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        crearTabla() 
        cargarDatos() 'Aqui se ejecuta la consulta sql y se genera el DataTable, que utilizo para cargar los items posteriormente
        cargarItems()
    End If
End Sub
```

Aquí mi consulta

> ```
> Protected Sub cargarDatos()
>     Dim consulta As String = ""
>     consulta = consulta & " DECLARE @FILTRO AS INTEGER; DECLARE @INFORME AS VARCHAR(10);"
>     consulta = consulta & " SET @FILTRO = " & rbFiltro.SelectedValue
>     consulta = consulta & " SET @INFORME = '" & ddlInformes.SelectedValue & "' "
>     consulta = consulta & " SELECT NRO_INFORME,NRO_PEDIDO,ANIO_RENDICION,PARTIDA,NRO_EXPEDIENTE,ID_EXPEDIENTE,N_EXPEDIENTE,ANIO_EXPEDIENTE,PERIODO"
>     consulta = consulta & " FROM VW_RECEPCION_ENVIOS "
>     consulta = consulta & " WHERE RECEPCIONADO_TCM = @FILTRO "
>     consulta = consulta & " AND NRO_INFORME LIKE @INFORME "
>     consulta = consulta & " GROUP BY NRO_INFORME,NRO_PEDIDO,PERIODO_ANIO,ANIO_RENDICION,PARTIDA,NRO_EXPEDIENTE,ID_EXPEDIENTE,N_EXPEDIENTE,ANIO_EXPEDIENTE,PERIODO"
>     Dim resultado As DataTable = New mcTabla().ejecutarConsulta(consulta)
>     For Each contenido In resultado.Rows
>         nuevoElemento(contenido("NRO_INFORME"), contenido("NRO_EXPEDIENTE"), contenido("NRO_INFORME"), contenido("NRO_PEDIDO"), contenido("PERIODO"), contenido("PARTIDA"), contenido("ID_EXPEDIENTE"), contenido("N_EXPEDIENTE"), contenido("ANIO_EXPEDIENTE"))
>     Next
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: puedes incorporar parte de tu código, incorpora el load

Comment: en tu dropdownlist debes habilitar el evento `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged`, para que al seleccionar un item de tu lista se realice el proceso que le indiques desde el `codebehind`